# Run JavaScript after Form Submit (Wordpress + WPPayForm)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, form-submit

I have a payment form on my Wordpress page and I would like to run a javascript code, after the form submit.

This is the code I'd like to submit:

```
ny.track({name: (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.get("utm_source"), value: 24.50, unit: "CHF"})
```

This is what I have on my Wordpress page:

```
jQuery(".wpf_submit_button").submit(function() {
     ny.track({name: (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.get("utm_source"), value: 24.50, unit: "CHF"});
    });
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. If I change this to fire on **click** (eg. `jQuery(".wpf_submit_button").click(function...` then it works without any problem, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. [Here is the link](https://landing.indigofitness.ch/internaltesting/) to a testpage with the code implemented. I am using [WPPayForm](https://wpmanageninja.com/downloads/wppayform-pro-wordpress-payments-form-builder/) for the payment form.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.submit()` is bound to the "Submit" javascript event according jQuery documentation. You should use your form id instead of the button class as jQuery selector:

```
jQuery("#wpf_form_id_354").submit(function() {
 ny.track({name: (new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.get("utm_source"), value: 24.50, unit: "CHF"});
});
```

Check jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

> The `submit` event is sent to an element when the user is attempting
> to submit a form. **It can only be attached to `<form>` elements.**

Comment: Thank you so much @Luismi ! That was it!

Comment: You're welcome @Paranoia :)